# Pushing to my own GitHub repo asking for credentials to git-ignored vendor dependencies

Tags: git, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project into which I have downloaded a variety of vendors (doctrine, jsmsecurityextrabundle and so on). These are ignored by the .gitignore file and managed by the framework vendors script. This is a typical Symfony2 setup for git.

My code is somewhere else in the folder structure under /web. I added/committed a new folder called research and issued a push. On pushing I am getting a series of login popups asking me to login to the doctrine project, asking me to login to the jmssecurityextrabundle project and so on for the vendors.

I am perplexed. There is nothing in the commit/push related to vendors, they are excluded.

I have done a new clone of my project and tried again with the same results.

I am new to Git. I am using Git within the PHPStorm (IDEA) IDE and other projects with similar setups have never exhibited this login-to-vendors issue.

I am not sure how to go about investigating this.

Comment: Does it work from the command line if you just do `git remote add github github_url` then `git push github master`?  If not, please post the error text.

Comment: Using the command line tools did lead me to sort this out. I had uncommitted files, and a merge conflict. Why that was causing my IDE to request vendor project credentials I have no idea, but it's all pushed now and happy. Thanks

Comment: This is why I don't trust git in IDEs! (even though I use PHPStorm too, and it's been one of the best investments in software I ever made) CLI FTW

Answer (score -2):

I know Symfony is using Git for their project, maybe you're having problems with their own .git/ in the vendor/ part ?

You should give your .gitignore, it may help !